# Ruby on Rails Session Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 3.0

After doing

```
rake db:sessions:create
```

then adding the line of code in the session_store.rb,

```
CouponManager::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

What else needs to be done before I'm capable of using sessions like

```
session[:ttl_qty] = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

That is all you should need to do. You should be able to use that session hash now and it should be persistent. Check out the following code.

## Controller

```
  before_filter :set_user
  def set_user
    if session[:user_id]
      @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
  end

  def login
    if user = User.find(params)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end
```

## View

```
<div>Hello, <%= @user.email %>!</div>
```

You can always take a look in the sessions table to make sure that your data is getting there... it should be in the data column (base64 encoded).  If you're using sqlite3, you can do something like this:

```
: sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3     
sqlite> select data from sessions limit 1;
... base64 data ...
```

You can decode the base64 data to see what is making it there. Hope that helps.